# NGINX failed after installing "nginx-extras"

Tags: nginx, debian

Installed through:

> apt-get install nginx-extras

After this, I tried do "service nginx restart" and "nginx -t" gets

> no port in upstream "php5-fpm-sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/[file]:84

Then I uninstalled nginx-extras

> apt-get remove nginx-extras

But problem has not solved, it seems during installation some config was changed.
Question is what config has changed and how to fix?
Nginx 1.13.12 on Debian 8.

Comment: During installation etc/nginx/nginx.conf was changed. Fortunately I had copy of nginx.conf, replacing old copy helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During instalation nginx-extras, it will ask smth about use current version of configs. Answer N.

Answer (score 0):

try and remove all nginx installed packages and install nginx-full